# 404 page generation issue news category filtered - Contao

Tags: contao

I have a page listing filtered news upon category filter . So I added news category list and news list filtered  modules in one page. The news list will show the news with selected category in the category list. The url generated for the news list filtered is 
**www.mysite/portFolio/categorie/cat**

When I change the url to **www.mysite/portFolio/categorie/cat.** (with a dot) the page is showing 404 . But the page contain some unwanted dumps in header like **...... itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" data-frontend-helper="......">**

I think the issue is coming from news_categories extension in which a 404 page generated in vendor/codefog/contao-news_categories/models/NewsModel.php (line no 98,99). My contao version is  4.5.8.
   How to solve this issue?

Comment: You need to provide more information.

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: Update the `codefog/contao-news_categories` package first to `^3.0`.

Comment: @fritzmg  Thank you Issue is solved. That was the problem.

Comment: @fritzmg  one more doubt,  in https://contao.org/en/extension-list/view/news_categories.html  the latest version is 2.8.9 . Is there any impact if we upgrade to 3.0 ? Is it compatible with my contao version ? Issue I reported having any big impact ???

Comment: You should always use the newest version, especially when you start a new project and especially when you start a new project with Contao 4. There is no point in using an older version.

Comment: When I upgrade my contao version to 4.5.8 the extension is automatically upgraded to 2.8 . And still the latest version showing in extension list is 2.8.10 . Whether any impact due to 3.0 version to my cotao version ? Is it compatible?

Comment: The extension list you are referring to is the old extension repository for Contao **3**. You are using Contao **4**. Of course version 3.x of the extension is compatible with your Contao version - otherwise you would not be able to install it via composer. Furthermore, version 3.x of the extension is specifically made for Contao 4.x.

Comment: @fritzmg Thank you

Comment: @fritzmg found an error when listing news by category filter . News with another category also listing. The new version need any new settings?

Comment: Please describe your problem in more detail in a new thread.

Comment: @fritzmg the issue was due to a hook $GLOBALS['TL_HOOKS']['newsListFetchItems'][]  in my custom module